# Autoclose Excel Workbook with warning popup

Tags: vba, excel, auto-close

I have a situation where multiple users will need to access a workbook (want to avoid using the 'Share Workbook' option due to all the problems). I've determined that a possible solution to this is to get the workbook to automatically close after 15 minutes of inactivity.

I would also like a message to pop up after the 15 minutes which alerts the user that unless they click the 'okay' button, the workbook will close. If they click the button, I would like the counter to start over, and ideally if they don't click anything the workbook will automatically closer after a further 1 minute.

I have found some code online which I have used. The workbook successfully closes after a specified time but I can't figure out how to get the message box to pop up. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Code I used is below:

In module 1:

```
Dim DownTime As Date

Sub SetTimer()
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("0:15:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure = "ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=False
 End Sub
Sub ShutDown()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

And in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call StopTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
 End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: MsgBox("times up?")?
That wont do?

Comment: On a second thought, if the workbook is inactive, showing a message box will not help because it requires user input, and the user might have already left. :-)

Comment: @dgorti then the worbook can be closed, as intended.

Comment: Do not close the workbook from "shutdown" sub rather write another sub for that purpose. Add an ontimer event in this sub (for 1 min) and invoke the new sub for real close. You may display the message from "Shutdown" sub as you wish.
Note: Do not use"msgbox" to display your message as it throws a dialogue box which needs to be interacted. Rather create a simple form for message display which can be unloaded after 1 min. I can give you a sample once I am done with my work

Answer (score 0):

Try the below `ShutDown` procedure:

```
Sub ShutDown()
    If CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp("Close Excel?", 60, "Excel", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal) = vbCancel Then
        StopTimer
        SetTimer
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Never 'share' Excel files on a network drive with coworkers.  You will encounter all kinds of problems, including workbook corruption, and other things.  Try this script, to auto-close your Excel files after n-minutes of inactivity.

To start, add the following code to a standard macro module. Note that there are three routines to be added:
Dim DownTime As Date

```
Sub SetTimer()
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("01:00:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure = "ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=False
 End Sub
Sub ShutDown()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

The next routines (there are four of them) need to be added to the ThisWorkbook object. Open the VBA Editor and double-click on the ThisWorkbook object in the Project Explorer. In the code window that Excel opens, place these routines:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call StopTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
```

See this for all info.

http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008192_Forcing_a_Workbook_to_Close_after_Inactivity.html